# Getting Error with Chaining Methods in python

Tags: python

I am newer with chaining methods in python. So I wanted to have best tutorial on this concept.I am getting an error after running below program.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
class sample():

    def __init__(self, kind=None):
        self.kind = kind

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.kind)

    def length(self):
        return len(self.kind)

    def toLowerCase(self):
        return 

    def text(self):
        self.kind = self.kind['input']['text']
        return self.kind



data = {"input":{"text":"data"}}
userinput = sample(data)
res = userinput.text.length()
print(res)
```

Expected Output:

```
data
4
```

Throwing an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-5e4c1fc240ab> in <module>()
      1 data = {"input":{"text":"data"}}
      2 userinput = sample(data)
----> 3 res = userinput.text.length()
      4 print(res)

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'length'
```

Please help me out on it to solve.

Comment: `userinput.text` is a method, a function object, which doesn't have a `.length` attribute. Your class definition doesn't support a fluent interface (i.e. by having `sample.text` return `self`), but even if it did, this would still fail. You'd have to use it like `userinput.text().length()`

Comment: you are right but still i am getting 4 as output not data and 4 together @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: Why do you expect `data` to be printed when you print `res`? `res` will always be `4`.

Answer (score 0):

```
print(userinput.text())
print(userinput.length())
```

Edited/

Comment: No, you are not getting my question clearly @Eshonai length() is a function itself which contains len() buddy.

Comment: edited. if you want to call it as userinput.text().length(), then you have to change the return statement of text method from self.kind to self.

Comment: I am getting output 4 but I want to have data and 4 together as output please check it out once

Comment: Consider explaining the answer, why this will help others as well why the above said thing was done.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call length() on your sample object, since text() will return a string type so channing, in this case, will call length on the returned value from text() (str) and length should be called on sample type object as I mentioned 
    class sample():

```
    def __init__(self, kind=None):
        self.kind = kind

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.kind)

    def length(self):
        return len(self.kind)

    def toLowerCase(self):
        return 

    def text(self):
        self.kind = self.kind['input']['text']
        return self.kind



data = {"input":{"text":"data"}}
userinput = sample(data)
res = userinput.text()
length = userinput.length()
print(res)
print(length)
```